# what is the best way to get model data without sending the id in public request?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm building online courses website in laravel. I want to display the teachers info in public pages and I don't want the id to be revealed in public requests. should I use UUID or encryption ?

for example :

```
teacher/1/courses
teacher/1/info
```

Comment: uuid is better, but you can use laravel builtin encrypt-decrypt method too, it will make your url long.  I'm using encrypt method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think uuid is the best approach, it's fairly readable, it is not cryptographical safe but seriously unpractical to break.

Pretty easy to implement using model binding. Imagine a route with this controller.

```
class CourseController {
    public function index(Teacher $teacher) {
        ...
    }
}

Route::get('teacher/{teacher}/courses', 'CourseController@index');
```

You need a uuid column on the model, do a migration for that. Else overwrite how model binding is resolved on the `Teacher.php` model.

```
class Teacher {
    public function getRouteKey(): string
    {
        return $this->uuid;
    }

    public function resolveRouteBinding($value, $field = null)
    {
        return self::where('uuid', $value)->firstOrFail();
    }
}
```

From here you just need to set uuid when you create your teacher model, hook into the creating event and it should be fine.

```
class Teacher {
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::creating(function ($model) {
            $model->uuid = resolve(UuidFactory::class)->uuid4();
        });
}
```

Comment: can you help me with this php question? please. its been long.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64081641/add-div-tag-inside-all-li-with-matching-class-name-using-php